# How do I create a list or set object in a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

For my project, the role of the Lecturer (defined as a class) is to offer projects to students. Project itself is also a class. I have some global dictionaries, keyed by the unique numeric id's for lecturers and projects that map to objects.

Thus for the "lecturers" dictionary (currently):

```
lecturer[id] = Lecturer(lec_name, lec_id, max_students)
```

I'm currently reading in a white-space delimited text file that has been generated from a database. I have no direct access to the database so I haven't much say on how the file is formatted. Here's a fictionalised snippet that shows how the text file is structured. Please pardon the cheesiness.

```
0001 001 "Miyamoto, S." "Even Newer Super Mario Bros"
0002 001 "Miyamoto, S." "Legend of Zelda: Skies of Hyrule"
0003 002 "Molyneux, P." "Project Milo"
0004 002 "Molyneux, P." "Fable III"
0005 003 "Blow, J." "Ponytail"
```

The structure of each line is basically `proj_id, lec_id, lec_name, proj_name`.

Now, I'm currently reading the relevant data into the relevant objects. Thus, `proj_id` is stored in `class Project` whereas `lec_name` is a `class Lecturer` object, et al. The `Lecturer` and `Project` classes are not currently related.

However, as I read in each line from the text file, for that line, I wish to read in the project offered by the lecturer into the `Lecturer` class; I'm already reading the `proj_id` into the `Project` class. I'd like to create an object in `Lecturer` called `offered_proj` which should be a set or list of the projects offered by that lecturer. Thus whenever, for a line, I read in a new project under the same `lec_id`, `offered_proj` will be updated with that project. If I wanted to get display a list of projects offered by a lecturer I'd ideally just want to use `print lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj`.

My Python isn't great and I'd appreciate it if someone could show me a way to do that. I'm not sure if it's better as a set or a list, as well.

`Update`

After the advice from [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293968/how-do-i-create-a-list-or-set-object-in-a-class-in-python/2293998#2293998) and [Oddthinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293968/how-do-i-create-a-list-or-set-object-in-a-class-in-python/2294002#2294002) I went back and made some changes and tried to print the results.

Here's the code snippet:

```
for line in csv_file:
    proj_id = int(line[0])
    lec_id = int(line[1])
    lec_name = line[2]
    proj_name = line[3]
    projects[proj_id] = Project(proj_id, proj_name)
    lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)
    if lec_id in lecturers.keys():
        lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj.add(proj_id)
    print lec_id, lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj
```

The `print lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj` line prints the following output:

```
001 set([0001])
001 set([0002])
002 set([0003])
002 set([0004])
003 set([0005])
```

It basically feels like the set is being over-written or somesuch. So if I try to print for a specific lecturer `print lec_id, lecturers[001].offered_proj` all I get is the last the `proj_id` that has been read in.

Comment: Hint: "all I get is the last the proj_id that has been read in."  What does the code for `lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj` actually do?  It must be creating a fresh, empty set.  Post that code, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set` is better since you don't care about order and have no duplicate.

You can parse the file easily with the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=sv#module-csv) module (with a `delimiter` of `' '`).

Once you have the `lec_name` you must check if that lecturer's already know; for that purpose, keep a dictionary from `lec_name` to lecturer objects (that's just another reference to the same lecturer object which you also refer to from the `lecturer` dictionary).  On finding a `lec_name` that's not in that dictionary you know it's a lecturer not previously seen, so make a new lecturer object (and stick it in both dicts) in that case only, with an empty set of offered courses.  Finally, just `.add` the course to the current lecturer's `offered_proj`.  It's really a pretty smooth flow.

Have you tried implementing this flow?  If so, what problems have you had?  Can you show us the relevant code -- should be a dozen lines or so, at most?

**Edit**: since the OP has posted code now, I can spot the bug -- it's here:

```
lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)
if lec_id in lecturers.keys():
    lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj.add(proj_id)
```

this is **unconditionally** creating a new lecturer object (trampling over the old one in the `lecturers` dict, if any) so of course the previous set gets tossed away.  This is the code you need:  **first** check, and create only if needed!  (also, minor bug, **don't** check `in....keys()`, that's horribly inefficient - just check for presence in the dict). As follows:

```
if lec_id in lecturers:
    thelec = lecturers[lec_id]
else:
    thelec = lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)
thelec.offered_proj.add(proj_id)
```

You could express this in several different ways, but I hope this is clear enough.  Just for completeness, the way I would normally phrase it (to avoid two lookups into the dictionary) is as follows:

```
thelec = lecturers.get(lec_id)
if thelec is None:
    thelec = lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)
thelec.offered_proj.add(proj_id)
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I actually am using `csv.reader` with `delimiter = ' '`. I didn't want to add that because I thought the question was getting a bit too verbose.

Comment: OK, so you already have what I suggested in the first paragraph;-).  The second paragraph should still be useful.

Comment: Tried pasting some code in here but it kind of failed miserably. I did what Oddthinking suggested: added the set creation in the `Lecturer` class. As I read in the parsed file, I'm setting: `proj_id = int(line[0])`  
I perform similar assignments for the other elements. Then read in all the relevant data into the global dictionaries: `projects[proj_id] = Project(proj_id, proj_name)` and `lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)`
After that I have an `if` statement that checks if the lecturer is actually in the dictionary and then it tries to add the project.

Comment: The problem is that when I call `lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj.add(proj_id)` I don't get a set of projects. I get a new set every time, i.e., it doesn't seem to be adding to the original set.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong and answered myself since I couldn't figure out how to post the code in the comments. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: PS - Thanks for the debug idea too. Will use that! The `lecturers.get(lec_id)` you used is similar to `if lec_id in lecturers` I take it? Any key differences?

Comment: @Az, don't add answers or comments to your questions: edit your original questions instead.  `.get` does a single look-up and therefore can be about twice as fast than `if...in` plus indexing, which does two lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are useful when you want to guarantee you only have one instance of each item. They are also faster than a list at calculating whether an item is present in the collection.

Lists are faster at adding items, and also have an ordering.

This sounds like you would like a set. You sound like you are very close already.

in Lecturer.**init**, add a line:

```
self.offered_proj = set()
```

That will make an empty set.

When you read in the project, you can simply add to that set:

```
lecturer.offered_proj.add(project)
```

And you can print, just as you suggest (although you may like to pretty it up.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm currently trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli) and [Oddthinking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8014/oddthinking)! I think I've figured out what was going on:

I modified the code snippet that I added to the question. Basically, every time it read the line I think it was recreating the lecturer object. Thus I put in another `if` statement that checks if `lec_id` already exists in the dictionary. If it does, then it skips the object creation and simply moves onto adding projects to the `offered_proj` set.

The change I made is:

```
if not lec_id in lecturers.keys():
    projects[proj_id] = Project(proj_id, proj_name)
lecturers[lec_id] = Lecturer(lec_id, lec_name)
lecturers[lec_id].offered_proj.add(proj_id)
```

I only recently discovered the concept behind `if not` thanks to my friend Samir.

Now I get the following output:

```
001 set([0001])
001 set([0001, 0002])
002 set([0003])
002 set([0003, 0004])
003 set([0005])
```

If I `print` for a chosen `lec_id` I get the fully updated set. Glee.

Comment: Excellent news. You can abbreviate that first line to be "if lec_id not in lecturers:"

Comment: Ooh, wait a moment. You are only creating the project if the lecturer is new. The second line of code shouldn't be inside the if-statement. It should always be run.